# External auto configured feign client not autowiring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I am creating an external jar to add as a dependency to multiple spring boot projects.
I am trying to make it auto configure itself to find and autowire a feign client.
When the application attempts to start it fails with:

FeignConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactory' that could not be found.

External project pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-lib-feign-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>java-lib-feign-client</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.8</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

External project Feign Client:

```
@FeignClient("java-app-c")
public interface MyFeignClient {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get(@RequestParam(name = "name") String name);
```

External project Feign Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(clients = MyFeignClient.class)
public class FeignConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private MyFeignClient feignClient;
}
```

External project spring.factories file (src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.abc.FeignConfiguration
```

For the EnableFeignClients annotation I have also tried using the base package of 'com.abc' but it doesn't change the result

Comment: Does your application, which uses external jar, have `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign` included as dependecy?